# bootstrap-datepicker range cant use endDate

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to set a range where the end date is not earlier than the start date. I want to make it as when the start date is chosen, for the end date option the date earlier than the start date will be disabled. But it's not making any changes to my calendar. I'm using bootstrap-datepicker, I saw a suggestion that says that maxDate is supported so I tried to use endDate but still it doesn't work. What can be done?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#clt_con_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#clt_con_end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
  });
  
  $("#clt_con_end").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#clt_con_date").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Contract Start Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="clt_con_date" id="clt_con_date" class="form- 
             control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Contract End Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="clt_con_end" id="clt_con_end" class="form- 
            control">
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Bootstrap datepicker has no method `setDefaults` to my knowledge. It would help if you'd be more clear what library we're talking about. Please revise your post to add detail and links.

Comment: I'm a beginner, so I followed an example I saw on the internet. I've edited my post, does that help?

Comment: No. I still see no reference to a _specific date picker library_. That's what I asked for. Bootstrap itself doesn't include a date picker.